# Thevenin resistance of a circuit, parallel or series?

Tags: resistors, thevenin

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKFY2w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I want the thevenin resistance of this circuit, do I add in series or parallel? Can't you do both? However, they yield different answers.

Comment: Suppose you apply a test voltage to the terminals...Will the current flow through these resistors as if they are in series or as if they are in parallel?

Comment: Closely related question: Are these resistors actually connected in parallel or in series?

Comment: We assume they are in parallel despite no current flowing?

Comment: They are connected a certain way. They are connected that way whether there is current flowing or not.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel. Don't let the lack of a voltage confuse you. The voltage is zero. Rth = R1 || R2.[image]